# How to validate a json with bravado-core against swagger and set the default value in python

Tags: python, json, swagger

I have defined a swagger 2.0 model. I want now to validate some json files against the swagger model. This  can do without any issue:

```
from bravado_core.spec import Spec
from bravado_core.validate import validate_object
...
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
spec_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "schema_3.yaml")
spec_dict = get_swagger_spec()
spec = Spec.from_dict(spec_dict, config=bravado_config)
...
ConfigObjDict = spec_dict['definitions']['Configuration']

...
def validate(configuration):
    validate_object(spec, ConfigObjDict, configuration)
...
with open('sample_3.json') as f:
    configuration = json.loads(f.read())
    validate(configuration)
```

The issue I have is that in the swagger file I defined some defaults associated to the definitions or the items and if the json file does not contains that item at all i would like to se the relative default, how can I do?

I tried to play with unmarshal or to dig in the bravado-core module (handle_null_value) but no luck for the moment.

I ends up by trying to loop into the json object and its relative definitions such as:

```
def set_defaults(in_spec, out_dict):
    in_spec = spec.deref(in_spec)
    pprint.pprint(in_spec)
    pprint.pprint(out_dict)
    for k_spec in in_spec:
        print k_spec
        if k_spec not in out_dict:
            try:
                d_value = in_spec[k_spec]['default']
                out_dict[k_spec] = d_value
            except:
                pass
```

But I got stuck because I do not know how to deref... (of course such solution should be recursive)

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the solution by my self, 
I made an error while passing the correct spec definition, 
and of course my method set_default needs to be recursive.
Here you are:

```
def _set_defaults(self, in_spec, out_dict):
    # by default resolve the references
    in_spec = self.spec.deref(in_spec)

    # if there is the key propriety,
    # resolve it directly avoiding useless loop
    if 'properties' in in_spec:
        in_spec = in_spec['properties']

    for k_spec in in_spec:
        if k_spec not in out_dict:
            # if an element defined in the swagger is not presend
            # in the json configuration, there are a lot of probabilities
            # it has a default value defined, let's try...
            try:
                d_value = in_spec[k_spec]['default']
                out_dict[unicode(k_spec, "utf-8")] = d_value
            except KeyError:
                pass

        else:
            if not isinstance(out_dict[k_spec], dict):
                continue
            self._set_defaults(in_spec[k_spec], out_dict[k_spec])
```

Of course if anyone has in mind a better ( builtin? ) solution, fell free to comment.
Thanks all